# How to avoid vscode breaking alignment?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, alignment

[image: broken alignment]

As the attachment image, left part is the alignment made manually, but when I use vscode to format the code file, the alignment is broken(as right part).

This is my vscode format settings:

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false,
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": false,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": false,
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
```

How to avoid this breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, auto format on save is a big no for me. Just do it manually. Prettier can help you with code that needs formatting.

```
 "editor.formatOnSave": false
```

Comment: I do need a formatOnSave function, but I just don't want it to format that alignment as the image shown. So I just want to ignore it only. Is there any config options to controll it?

Comment: Hmm, it should be prettier thats auto intending your code. Maybe this can help you
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/code-formatting-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I have read the prettier's options and configurations manual, but I haven't found any solution for this.